# MATLAB - translate colour image from file

Tags: matlab, plot, png

I have a colour PNG image and I need to translate it and plot the result, which should have the same colour scale of the original image. Using the code below I get as a result a greyscale image; do you know how to fix this? Thanks!

```
[E_col, map_E] = imread('E.png');
shift_vert = 35; % 152
shift_hor = 30;
E_col_shift = zeros(size(E_col,1) + shift_vert, size(E_col,2) + shift_hor);
E_col_shift = imtranslate(E_col_shift,[shift_hor, shift_vert]);
figure; imshow(E_col_shift, map_E);
```

Here you can find the image I am working with:[image]

Comment: can you post a download link to your image? If you post in in SO it will be converted to jpg, changin the format and behaviour (possibly) of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typografical error:

```
% // This image is JUST ZEROES!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
E_col_shift = zeros(size(E_col,1) + shift_vert, size(E_col,2) + shift_hor);


%// So why are you translating the empthy image?!?!?!
E_col_shift = imtranslate(E_col_shift,[shift_hor, shift_vert]);

%// It should be the original image!!!!!
E_col_shift = imtranslate(E_col,[shift_hor, shift_vert]);
```